# How can I prevent a user to login in Laravel if already logged on another device in the best possible way?

Tags: laravel

My purpose is not to logout a user from the old device, but to prevent them to login if already logged.

I could use a flag in a column of the user table, but it doesn't seem an elegant and modular way. What if for some reason the user is logged out without calling the normal method in the controller so the flag is not set to false and they can't login anymore?

Sure, I could track whether some time passed, but it doesn't seem an elegant way.

I'm sure there is a simpler solution. For example, is there a way to check if a session id is still valid (so if the user is logged in somewhere)? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I mean that I don't want the user to login from a different device if already logged, not from the same one!

Comment: api login or web login?

Comment: Web login⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: Usually you logout the old device. Why do you want to keep him logged in and prevent any other logins?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be complicated to check user's all session ids you can have a column of `current_login_at` which you will need to set on login and set it null on logout.

Also you know that Default session last 2 hours and you can make a check before login.